# Access Siri through iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, siri

I am making an app in which I want to implement the concept of Siri/Voice recognition. I have tried [this](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) but did not get the output exactly it is not recognizing the word properly. Anyone has an idea that how to convert speech into text? How to access Siri functionality. If anyone know about this implementation then please let me know.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access Siri features, Apple didn't provide public API for Siri :-S .

The best APIs I've seen is the openears and [Dragon Mobile SDK](http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon-mobile-sdk/index.htm).

Answer (score 7):

You can't access Siri interface directly but there is nice trick to deal with Siri commands. You can implement `UITextField` and capture text which will be written there by Siri, that way you can make your app executing spoken commands.

You can find more explanation for that subject here:
[Siri trick](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/11/23/in-which-i-use-siri-to-create-in-app-third-party-commands-while/?a_dgi=aolshare_twitter)

Comment: for that link have no code how is it work, and explanation not clear, can u post some code here?