# How to check siri status in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How would I check whether settings for "Siri" has been enabled on iPhone devices(iPhone 4s and 5) or not programmatically?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i don't want to implement siri in my app, i just want to check is it enabled in settings or not?
please tell why it gets -ve, is there any process for this it's urgent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to find out using public APIs. Apple doesn't expose a lot of the users' system preferences on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't provide a public API for Siri.

I think you should have a look there : [Access Siri through iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068429/access-siri-through-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the following link

http://www.tuaw.com/2011/11/23/in-which-i-use-siri-to-create-in-app-third-party-commands-while/?a_dgi=aolshare_twitter

Hope this will help you